# Rosetta stopped working in a virtualized Snow Leopard hosted in Mavericks (Parallels or Virtualbox)

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, virtualization, rosetta

I have successfully installed Snow Leopard in a VirtualBox on my Macbook Pro Retina Early 2013 (running OS X Mavericks).

While I can start the virtualized Snow Leopard in Oracle's Virtualbox or Parallels, I have no luck starting any Rosetta Application from within Snow Leopard. This happens even after a fresh install of Snow Leopard before any updates.
All Rosetta applications fail to start or even to be install.

Anyone know a configuration which allows using Rosetta in a virtualized Snow Leopard Environment?

The software versions I am using:

- Virtualbox Versions: 4.1, 5.0, 5.1
- Parallels Version: 8

Comment: Is the Mac OS X Snow Leopard the typical Desktop version or is it the Server version?

Comment: @klanomath, I have looked at that thread, however, there is nothing specific for Rosetta mentioned therein. I mean they do not even confirm that a Rosetta application was successfully started. Nevertheless, thanks for you attention!

Comment: @klanomath, I downloaded a trial version of Parallels 11 and unfortunately it did not work either. : ( I guess it must be related to my hardware. Maybe the Macbook Pro is the problem.

Comment: @klanomath, I also have an Intel Core i7, my VM has 4096GB RAM. I am trying with fewer memory now.

Comment: @elcojon I also had 4 GB RAM. Did you create a **new** VM with Snow Leo Server (I think you have to choose to install Rosetta in the OS X installer set up - I don't really remember)?

Comment: @klanomath, You can choose to install Rosetta any time once you start a PPC application. I have tried both ways. But I haven't created a new VM, since the install consumes so much time. I guess I have to try another day.

Comment: @klanomath, finally I got it working after are reinstall. It seems that my originally installation, which was based on Virtual Box, was performed for 32-Bits. When installing with a 64-bit OS target, all worked.

Comment: @elcojon Well done! Please write an answer mentioning the 64-bit vs. 32-bit thing.

Comment: @klanomath, it seems that the 64bit/32bit thing was not the only change I made in the new installation. I could further narrow down the cause in the type of hard disk type. so when creating the VM in Oracle's VirtualBox, using a vmdk, vdi, or vhd type hard disk will fail Rosetta, however, using the (Parallels) hdd type hard disk will result in a working Rosetta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the type of the hard disk I initially chose for installing Snow Leopard on matters.
So, when creating the virtual hard disk drive in VirtualBox, selecting a "hdd" Parallels type file, was the key. I tried with VDI, and VMDK (VMware) but all installations with these lead to a sucessful install of Snow Leopard, but a non-functioning Rosetta.